# Store Array Javascript to PHP with session

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, session

I want to store array from index.html to file.php with $_SESSION but I'm getting stuck (I don't know how to store and access it, since im new in php).

Here my codes in **index.html**:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $_SESSION["myArray"] = $array;
?>
$(function generateArray (parameter) {

 var array = ["hello","world"];

});
```

Here my codes in file.php:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  //print_r($_SESSION["myArray"]) --> how can I do that?
 ?>
```

Can somebody help me? :')

Comment: php execute in the server.if you want to pass js array use ajax

Comment: @FastSnail can you teach me how? :(

Comment: Why You want to use JavaScript? Maybe simple HTML form will be enough?

Comment: @RafalKozlowski actually I have file-upload feature in html and already had an array of string from that file. So, what i have to do now is pass that array to file.php :''(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your scenario, You can send ajax request to store array on session

**In index.html**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var array = ["hello","world"];
   $.post('store_session.php',{data:array}, function(response){
      alert(response);
   });
});
```

**In store_session.php**

```
 <?php
      session_start();
      $_SESSION['my_array']=$_POST['data'];
      echo "data stored in session";
```

**Now call file.php from browser**

```
 <?php
      session_start();
      print_r($_SESSION['my_array']);
```

Comment: omg thank you for answering my stupid question :''

Comment: glad to here from you.. welcome.. don't forget to mark as correct :)

Comment: Just wanna ask something, what if I upload file.csv through index.html and want to pass it to file.php? what should I do with ajax?

Answer (score 0):

You have two main options to get your data from javascript to PHP

1. Using AJAX (GET or POST)
2. Storing it in a Cookie

You can choose to pass your array as plain text or json. JSON is the best choice in my opinion.

#### Option one - using cookies

For this option I advice to use a library such as jQuery Cookie.

```
// Javascript
var jsonArray = ["hello","world"];
$.cookie("example", jsonArray); // Sample 1

// PHP
var_dump(json_decode($_COOKIE['example']));
```

#### Option two - Using ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/index.php',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: jsonArray
});

// PHP
var_dump($_POST);
```

I have not put in too much detail but I think this should help you on your way. Good luck!.

Comment: omg! thank you :'), just wanna ask something, what if I upload file.csv through index.html and want to pass it to file.php? what should I do with ajax?